# Using a file location in a VLOOKUP issue

Tags: vba, excel

I got this code from another answer on here and it is better than they way I was doing it because you can actually just select where you are pulling your file from. But it seems like I can't get the file name exactly correct in the VLOOKUP? I get error 1004 right after the VLOOKUP. Maybe there is something else wrong. I copied this code then replaced what I needed but I need another pair of eyes. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim x As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long

x = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
    Title:="Choose previous quarter's file", MultiSelect:=False)

MsgBox "You selected " & x
'Find the last instance in the string of the path separator "\"
lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(x, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
x = Left$(x, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(x, Len(x) - lNewBracketLocation)

Range("V2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & x & "]file_2017072732'!$B$5:$AP$9486,18,FALSE)"
' ERROR 1004
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("V2:V177")
Range("V2:V177").Select
```

When I get to that point it shows that x is equal to `"C:\Name\Name\Name\[Filename.xlsx"`.

Is that the format it should be?

Comment: @YowE3k Oh that wasn't actually it. In my main post the slash was there... but I guess it caused a formatting issue I put another one in and it showed up correctly. There is actually a slash there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the value of `x`, which looks like it is in a valid format.

The problem lies with assigning a formula, written using `A1` notation, to a cell using its `FormulaR1C1` property.

Change

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & x & "]file_2017072732'!$B$5:$AP$9486,18,FALSE)"
```

to either

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & x & "]file_2017072732'!$B$5:$AP$9486,18,FALSE)"
```

or

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC5,'" & x & "]file_2017072732'!R5C2:R9486C42,18,FALSE)"
```

and it should be OK.

Comment: yeah I ended up switching the other parts to R5C2 and so on and I actually just got it working. But I don't like using that. I copied that formula and didn't switch that out because some of my other formulas use it like when you make a macro it uses that for some reason. Thanks for your help! I am thinking it should work once I fix all of that back to A1!