# VBA Formula: Variable File Name and Variable Sheet Name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a cell reference to a cell in another workbook.  In my code below, I am using a variable for workbook name and sheet name.

- `SourceFileNamePath` = Path and name of workbook I am linking to
- `SourceTab` = Tab in the workbook I want to link to

Though the code runs fine, the formula generated is not working.  Does anyone have any thoughts on whether I am referencing `SourceFileNamePath` and `SourceTab` correctly?

Code is below:

```
Cells(destStartRow, destStartCol).FormulaR1C1 = "='[" & SourceFileNamePath & "]" & SourceTab & "'!R" & sourceStartRow & "C" & sourceStartCol
```

Comment: Only the file **name** should be enclosed in brackets - e.g. `='C:\Temp\Data\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!R5C10`.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46162966/6535336) for a possible way of setting it up.)

Answer (score 3):

The format to access a cell in a sheet in an external workbook is

`'path\[filename]sheetname'!cell_reference`

so if you have a variable called `SourceFileNamePath` containing the path **and** filename (e.g. `"C:\Temp\Data\Book1.xlsx"`) then you need to separate the filename from the path.

You could use something like:

```
SourceFileNamePath = "C:\Temp\Data\Book1.xlsx"   ' or however you set that variable
SourceTab = "Sheet1"                             ' or however you set that variable

Dim SourceFilePath As String
Dim SourceFileName As String
SourceFilePath = Left(SourceFileNamePath, InStrRev(SourceFileNamePath, Application.PathSeparator))
SourceFileName = Mid(SourceFileNamePath, InStrRev(SourceFileNamePath, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)
Cells(destStartRow, destStartCol).FormulaR1C1 = "='" & SourceFilePath & "[" & SourceFileName & "]" & SourceTab & "'!R" & sourceStartRow & "C" & sourceStartCol
```

---

Note: If either the path or the filename contains any single-quotation marks (e.g. if the filename was `Sukhbir's test file.xlsx`) then it will need to be escaped (i.e. each single-quotation mark needs to be replaced by two single-quotation marks).  This can be achieved by using the `Replace` function, e.g.:

```
Cells(destStartRow, destStartCol).FormulaR1C1 = _
                                 "='" & Replace(SourceFilePath, "'", "''") & _
                                 "[" & Replace(SourceFileName, "'", "''") & "]" & _
                                 SourceTab & "'!R" & sourceStartRow & "C" & sourceStartCol
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!  I spent 3+ hours yesterday trying to figure this out, I am glad I asked for help.  :)  Thank you again for your help.